# Non-trivial blocks when $S_n$ acts naturally on $[n]$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $S_n$ be a symmetric group of $n$ elements acting on set by a natural map $$\pi : S_n \times[n] \mapsto [n]$$

As we know that there will be exactly one orbit because the action $\pi$ is transitive in this case. If we see the orbital graph it will be complete graph means every possible edge will be there in the graph.

**Orbital graph :** $G=(V,E)$, where $V=[n]$, $E = \{(i ,j) \in E, \exists \sigma , i^{\sigma} = j\}$.

> Question : I want to find the non-trivial [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(permutation_group_theory)) which contain $5$. I don't know how to proceed further, please help.

Comment: 5 in which sense - you consider $S_5$? And what is a "block"?

Comment: No I want to find a non trivial block which contain 5 as an element.

Comment: This action is primitive.

Comment: @ Derek Holt , So you are saying there is no non-trivial block at all.